# How can I add a unit test for a new class stub?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to add a unit test for a newly minted (usually empty) class into my unit test project in the appropriate folder with a single key command. How can i do this? I'd even go so far as writing code to do this as it would greatly expedite my normal coding practices. I'm not sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which version of Visual Studio we are talking about. For Visual Studio  2012 / 2013 there is the [Generate Unit Test Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7). It is a pretty decent solution, with some minor quirks, such as no possibility to define a default test-project name.

If you have access to [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) - and I recommend you at least try it out - there is also the possibility of file and live-templates, which allow for rather fast method and class generation.

For example, you might use the shortcut `Alt+Ctrl+Ins` to quickly generate a unit test template (which you will have to create in advance).

Then, using a user defined shortcut (e.g. typing `test+TAB`) you may quickly generate a test-method stub. This solution is easy to customize, but you will have to invest some time to create your templates.

More information on templates can be found [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Speed+up+creation+of+unit+tests).

Comment: I like it. The only trouble I have is that my test namespace isn't "Project.My.Namespace.Tests". It is "Project.Test.My.Namespace". That's Visual Studio's naming convention not mine.

Comment: @Jordan Yeah, its not perfect. Unfortunately, the source code does not seem to be available, so the chances of making individual changes are rather slim.